# Create a table based on a query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

The title may be misleading, but I'm unsure of another way of phrasing it. The query below works as intended if a little slow. However, when I try wrapping an `INSERT INTO` around the query, it locks up the database. `Table1` contains less than 1,000 records and `Table2` is less than 1,500 records.

The objective of the query is to match records based on the date/time groups contained in columns from Tables 1 and 2. The crux of the problem is getting the result set into a unique table so it can be exported.

This query is a variation of what I could find here and may clarify my intentions: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1305b3a9-94c9-4e7c-a5fe-7b64a79600ca/select-closest-earlier-date. The change is rather than looking for the closest date after, I'm retrieving the closest day prior.

```
SELECT Table1.*, (
    SELECT Table2.Column1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Column1 = (
        SELECT Max(T.Column1) FROM Table2 AS T WHERE T.Column1 <= Table1.Column1)) AS TempCol FROM Table1
```

Are there any alternatives I can attempt to break up this SQL or is my only option to let it run until it's complete?

Example of output:

```
Table1.ID     Table1.Column1     T.Column1
1             2/1/2015 12:00     2/1/2015 08:30
2             2/1/2015 12:15     2/1/2015 08:30
3             2/1/2015 12:30     2/1/2015 08:30
4             2/1/2015 12:45     2/1/2015 08:30
5             2/1/2015 13:00     2/1/2015 12:55
```

Comment: Can you use common English to describe what you're after and provide data examples with expected results?  I'm having a hard time discerning what the SQL is trying to do. (other than create a new table got that part)

Comment: So the comparisons are all based on date/time groups to find the closest date prior in Table 2 to the date/time group in Table 1. I don't necessarily need all fields from Table 1, but it doesn't make the process more efficient and I am looking to merge the two tables together based on the matching dates so it ends up making little difference here.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what your SQL does here but whenever I have small tables that are taking a long time to do thing the solution usually ends up revolving around indexing columns correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to insert the result of your query into a new table:

```
SELECT * INTO newTable FROM (
  SELECT Table1.*, (
    SELECT Table2.Column1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Column1 = (
        SELECT Max(T.Column1) FROM Table2 AS T WHERE T.Column1 <= Table1.Column1))     AS TempCol FROM Table1
)
```

Then run an INSERT INTO using `SELECT * FROM newTable` as the query.

But based on what you said you need, why don't you just run something like this:

```
select table1.*
, (select max(t2.column1) from table2 as t2 where t2.column1 < table1.column1) as t2col1
from table1
```

or

```
select table1.ID, table1.column1, max(table2.column1)
from table1 
left join table2 on  table2.column1 < table1.column1
group by table1.ID,  table1.column1
```

That gets all records from table1, along with the maximum date from table2 where table2's column1 is less than table1's column1.

Comment: I am currently running this solution. Status after about 15 minutes of run time is ~35% complete.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. This seemed to do the trick. Only downside is it took 36 minutes to run. Looking for ways to speed that up. It may be an indexing problem, but I have no idea right now.

Comment: @WeeZ, I updated my answer with a query that might help.  It's unclear from your question what the "date/time groups" are but the above gets you dates from table2 that are less than the date in table1.